# Custom TableViewCell Button should toggle active status and icon of a specific row, but it also changes the icon of other unrelated rows

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, custom-cell

I need to **toggle a per-object state (active/inactive) in a `tableView` that contains custom objects**: I want to show only active objects in that `tableView`, so when the state of an object changes to inactive, it disappears from the list.

The app is working (creating new custom objects, displaying them in the `tableView`, viewing and editing their content - including the active/inactive status - in a detailView...); in case it is relevant, please consider that **my project uses Core Data** and that I use its methods to populate the `tableView`.

I also need a custom design for the `tableView` cells, which I've already implemented (I have a **subclass of `UITableViewCell` and the custom cells displaying the desired content**) and that too seems to work, but it's my first time with custom cells and I must have done something wrong...

**When I tap the active-inactive button in the cell to change the custom object status** (and make it disappear from the list because it has become inactive), **I actually get what I want for that object** (its status changes and the object disappears from the list).

**My issue is that I also see the image of the `UIButton` (which shows two different icons when the object is active or inactive) of a few other rows change to the inactive icon.** Normally the button image of all rows, except the one I just tapped and that is already disappeared, should be the active one.
**Please consider that, for these other rows, it's only the icon that is wrong, the actual status is still active for every row I haven't tapped**: if I stop the app and run it again, on startup the icons are all right, and in the `tableView` I only see the objects that are still active.

I'm pretty sure my issue is related to `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier, but I don't know what to do to fix the issue.

Here are a few of my methods:

```
// TableViewController

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as MyCustomTableViewCell

    self.configureCell(cell, atIndexPath: indexPath)

    return cell
}


func configureCell(cell: MyCustomTableViewCell, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    let aObject = self.fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as CustomObject

    cell.customLabel.text = aObject.name
    cell.detailLabel.text = aObject.anotherProperty
    //...

    cell.objectToMarkAsInactive = aObject
}


// MyCustomTableViewCell

//... IBOutlets

var objectToMarkAsInactive : CustomObject?

@IBAction func markObjectAsInactive(sender: AnyObject) {

    activeButton.selected = !activeButton.selected

    objectToMarkAsInactive?.active = !(objectToMarkAsInactive?.active as Bool)

    saveContext()
}


override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()

    // UIImage vars

    activeButton.setImage(activeImage, forState: UIControlState.Selected)
    activeButton.setImage(inactiveImage, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    activeButton.setImage(highlightedImage, forState: UIControlState.Highlighted)
}
```

I also tried to reload the `tableView` after saving the context, but the icon issue on other rows remains.

Clearly, my solution to set the custom property of cell `objectToMarkAsInactive = aObject in configureCell` of TableViewController isn't the right one, since the cells are reused, but I have no other ideas to accomplish what I want, since the status-changing button of the cell has to be connected as IBAction to MyCustomTableViewCell and not to TableViewController.

I'm pretty new to programming, and probably my issue is caused by bad decisions on my part, but I could really use some suggestions, I'm stuck...

I should stop using `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier`? I wouldn't like it, because potentially I could have a significant amount of objects, but if I have to use normal cells, can I have a custom design for them without deque? The "regular" cell instantiation method shows only a few options for normal cells, not custom ones, in an enum (`UITableViewCellStyle.`).

Thanks in advance,

@cdf1982

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to stop using `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier`. The issue is that the cells are being reused, but if it's just the image for the button that is incorrect, add in a check to see which image needs to be displayed.

```
func configureCell(cell: MyCustomTableViewCell, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    let aObject = self.fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as CustomObject

    cell.customLabel.text = aObject.name
    cell.detailLabel.text = aObject.anotherProperty
    //...
    if aObject.isActive { // set button to active }
    else { // set button to inactive }

    cell.objectToMarkAsInactive = aObject
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this worked just fine. Before implementing your suggestion (which proofs that sometimes I should just stop hitting a wall and try a different perspective) I've throughly checked that the only thing wrong was the image, and since that's the case, I've added an if/else to check the .active property of the object in the configureCell method, setting the .selected property of the button accordingly. It's working just fine, I really appreciate your help!

Comment: Not a problem! I was stuck on this same thing a while ago and it was so frustrating to try to figure out.